# Javascript Text Statistic Algorithm Improvement

Tags: javascript, node.js, statistics

I am trying to solve one algorithm in Javascript where the user requires the input sentence  then have to do statistic as the following screenshot

[image]

I have done with following code

```js
class TextAnalytics {

  getAnalytics(sentence) {
    var analyzedResult = {}
    var textArray = new Array();
    const trimmed = sentence.replace(/\s/g, '').toUpperCase()
     for (let i = 0; i < trimmed.length; i++) {
        const currentChar = trimmed[i]
        if (!analyzedResult[currentChar]) {
          analyzedResult[currentChar] = {
            count: 1,
            prevChar: trimmed[i - 1] ? [trimmed[i - 1]] : [],
            nextChar: trimmed[i + 1] ? [trimmed[i + 1]] : [],
            index: [i]
          }
        } else {

          analyzedResult[currentChar].count++
          trimmed[i - 1] &&
            analyzedResult[currentChar].prevChar.push(trimmed[i - 1])
          trimmed[i + 1] &&
            analyzedResult[currentChar].nextChar.push(trimmed[i + 1])
       
          analyzedResult[currentChar].index.push(i)
        }
      }
      return analyzedResult;
  }
 
  getMaxDistance(arr) {
      let max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
      let min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
      return max - min;
  }
  
}
var textAnalytics = new TextAnalytics();
console.log(textAnalytics.getAnalytics("its cool and awesome"));
```

Want to check if there is any other way to solve this problem or any refactoring require

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it more elegantly:

```
class CharStats {
    constructor () {
        this.prevs = [];
        this.nexts = [];
        this.indexes = [];
    }

    add (prev, next, index) {
        prev && this.prevs.push(prev);
        next && this.nexts.push(next);
        this.indexes.push(index);

        return this;
    }

    get count () {
        return this.indexes.length;
    }

    get maxDistance () {
        // If the index array is empty, the result will be Infinite.
        // But because the algorithm cannot have a situation where 
        // this class is used without at least one index, this case 
        // need not be covered.
        return Math.max(...this.indexes) - Math.min(...this.indexes);
    }
}

const getAnalytics = sentence =>
    [...sentence.replace(/\s/g, '').toUpperCase()].reduce((map, cur, i, arr) =>
        map.set(cur, (map.get(cur) || new CharStats).add(arr[i - 1], arr[i + 1], i)),
        new Map);

console.log(getAnalytics('its cool and awesome'));
```

Comment: how to iterate and where to use count, maxDistance method

Comment: @user11229655 You can print it like this: ```console.table([...getAnalytics('its cool and awesome').entries()].map(([char, { count, maxDistance }]) => ({ char, count, maxDistance })))```. Anyway, you can read about ```Map```. Among other things, it also has a useful ```forEach``` function.

Comment: nave sade how to add next, prev in the table

Comment: ```console.table([...getAnalytics('its cool and awesome').entries()].map(([char, { prevs, nexts, count, maxDistance }]) => ({ char, count, maxDistance, prevs: prevs.join(', '), nexts: nexts.join(', ') })))```

Answer (score 1):

1) Convert string to array of chars, remove empty, change to upper case
2) Use reduce, go thru each char and build object 'keys' as Char values to have before, after and index.
3) if Char already exist in object, Append new stats and calculate max-distance.

```js
const getAnalytics = str => {
  const caps = Array.from(str.toUpperCase()).filter(x => x.trim());
  return caps.reduce((acc, char, i) => {
      const prepost = { 
        before: caps[i-1] || '', 
        after: caps[i+1] || '',
        index: i
      };
      if (char in acc) {
        const chars = [...acc[char].chars, prepost];
        const mm = chars.reduce((acc, curr) => ({
          max: Math.max(acc.max, curr.index),
          min: Math.min(acc.min, curr.index)
        }), {max: -Infinity, min: Infinity});
        acc[char] = { chars, max_distance: mm.max - mm.min };
      } else {
        acc[char] =  { chars: [prepost], max_distance: 0 };
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
}

console.log(getAnalytics('its cool and awesome'));
```